# Different results when calculating with floats instead of integers

Tags: python

Why does using float instead of int give me different results when all of my inputs are integers?

```
from deepface import DeepFace 
import cv2 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import webbrowser
from turtle import *
import turtle
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
pause = 0

def happy():
    print("Vani, Gỗ đàn hương, Hoa nhài và Hương thảo")
    webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LjhCEhWiKXk&list=PL1VuYyZcPYIJTP3W_x0jq9olXviPQlOe1")
    tur = turtle.Screen()
    tur.bgcolor("pink")
    tur.title("Light")
    turtle.done()

def sad():
    print("Sả chanh, Cam Bergamot, Húng quế và Nhục đậu khấu")
    webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LanCLS_hIo4&list=PLWOvS8Nliu2x6LvCNnRydpT-owR8zxXB7")
    tur = turtle.Screen()
    tur.bgcolor("yellow")
    tur.title("Light")
    turtle.done()

def neutral():
    print("Gừng, Bưởi và Chanh")
    webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ru0K8uYEZWw&list=PLVgakZ6MigxxNhXZae5cALEW588-sMQn6")
    tur = turtle.Screen()
    tur.bgcolor("orange")
    tur.title("Light")
    turtle.done()

def angry():
    print(" Oải hương, Hoa hồng, Cúc la mã và Ylang-Ylang")
    webbrowser.open("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qq-RGFyaq0U&list=PLefKpFQ8Pvy5aCLAGHD8Zmzsdljos-t2l")
    tur = turtle.Screen()
    tur.bgcolor("green")
    tur.title("Light")
    turtle.done()

while True:

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    try:
        result = DeepFace.analyze(frame, actions=['emotion'])
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)
        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
        cv2.putText(frame, result['dominant_emotion'], (50, 50), font, 3, (0, 0, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_4)

        if result['dominant_emotion'] == "happy" and pause == 0:
            happy()
        if result['dominant_emotion'] == ["sad","tear"] and pause == 0:
            sad()
        if result['dominant_emotion'] == "angry" and pause == 0:
            angry()
        if result['dominant_emotion'] == "neutral" and pause == 0:
            neutral()

    except:
        pass
    cv2.imshow('Emotional Expression', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(2) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Which floats/ints are you referring to?

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre], and try to explain the problem clearly. Which floats, which integers? How are you "using" them? What "results" are different, and why, in your view, should they be the same?

Comment: where do you use `float` instead of `int`? What difference do you get?  Don't expect that we will run code to see problem. Besides code may work correctly on our computers.

Comment: code could be more readable if you would use `pause = False` and later put all `ifs` in `if not pause: ... all other if ....`

Comment: if you what to check one of two values then this will not work `result['dominant_emotion'] == ["sad","tear"]` - it has to be `result['dominant_emotion'] == "sad" or result['dominant_emotion'] == "tear"` or you have to use `in` instead of `==` - `result['dominant_emotion'] in ["sad","tear"]`

Comment: using `except: pass` can be wrong idea - you may get some unexpected error and you can't see it. You should do at least `except Exception as ex: print(ex)`.